# How to preserve number's precision while converting list to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

My initial result is in `int_list` is it possible to preserve the precision?

**Code:**

```
print(int_list)
int_list = np.array(int_list)
print(int_list)
```

**Result:**

```
[0.027442146241428052, 0.14086078558393686, 0.20105874001152255, 0.09721367288504784, 0.01733800399804374]
[0.02744215 0.14086079 0.20105874 0.09721367 0.017338  ]
```

Comment: precision is the same (float64 by default), it's just how numpy prints it differently. See the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) You can confirm with `for x in int_list: print(x)`

Comment: on an unrelated note: having decimal fractions in something called an "int list" may not be the best idea.

Comment: You can adjust the printout precision using `np.set_printoptions`. It looks like you have 18 decimals, so you can use `np.set_printoptions(precision=18)` before printing the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the display - python and numpy both show you only part of the 53 bits of precision - and that's converted to decimal and rounded. Had you assigned to a different variable, say, `arr`, you could test `arr[0] == int_list[0]`.